# Making a "definition" by way of a universal property

Tags: universal-property, article-writing

This is somewhat a question out writing styles.  In a paper, I want to introduce and "define" an object $X$ by just stating the universal properties which is satisfies.  Logically, this is not quite right, as one should also show *existence*, but I can just refer to a reference for this.  My motivation is that I only need to *use* the universal property, and not the messy details of the actual construction.

It is a bit hard to talk in generalities, so let's just say that in particular $X$ is a normed vector space, and for some subset $X_0$ of $X$, I state as part of the properties that

- $\|x\|\leq 1$ for each $x\in X_0$.

I then remark that actually, once you have all the properties, it follows that really $\|x\|=1$ for each $x\in X_0$.

As far as I can see, to *prove* this stronger condition, you actually need *some* explicit construction of $X$, which does satisfy this stronger condition, and then apply the universal property to conclude that any realisation of $X$ must have this property.

> This is logically sound, but from a writing style, it seems a little perverse, as it hides from the reader how to prove the statement.

Thinking more, there is something slightly surprising happening here, in that the universal property implies fact (Y) but the only way to prove fact (Y) is to appeal to an explicit construction.

> Does anyone have examples of this phenomena in other writing?  Should I be worried about this presentation style?

Comment: if I understand your question properly, it seems that the presentation of real numbers also goes like this. Very often, the real numbers are axiomatically treated as an ordered field with the supremum property. The existence of such a field is often left to some appendix or referenced to some other text. As a first introduction, the only thing we "care about" are the various properties it satisfies. In my opinion, as long as the author makes it very clear that the existence of such an object is something non trivial to prove, and provides a clear reference, I think it's fine to omit details

Comment: I was trying to make this point: Yes, that's what I do, but there is an _extra_ property on my object X which I seemingly cannot prove _directly_ from the universal property, but instead can only check by looking at a construction. I think the real numbers are _not_ like this: I can't think of a property of the reals which I ever use which is only apparent from e.g. looking at Dedekind cuts...